# Possible to specify artifactory to install python packages from when using pip and distutils setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

I have a python program packaged with distutils, where a number of dependencies are specified in the setup.py file under the `install_requires` section.

Up until now these python packages have been sourced from the default location on the internet. However, now I would like to use our internal Artifactory to source all python packages, and to throw an error if the dependency is not found in the internal Artifactory.

Is there a configuration option or ENV variable that may be changed to force distutils to source packages from an internal artifactory?

I would also like to force this requirement within certain virtual environments, such that pip will not install a package unless it can install it from the internal Artifactory

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to [configure pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#configuration) to use your internal Artifactory as `index-url`.

Also you can try to restrict `easy_install` with [allow-hosts](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#restricting-downloads-with-allow-hosts).